# Glightbox implementation

Tags: lightbox, lightbox2, react-image-lightbox

I am unable to use onOpen and onClose functions of Glightbox. I wanted to add animation inside Glight, but since it's a js library, I am unable to understand the way it works. Is there a library that I can use to get the same functionality?

Glightbox is used previously